# A Fantasy Gathering

Tags: wordplay, chemistry, animals

At the gathering of the fantasy creatures, a small group of elemental beasts gathered at the bar.

"Oh, interesting!" said the cat, "if you remove two letters from your type, you have your name!"

"Wow, that's right," agreed the horse, "and it seems that if you remove three letters from your name, you are left with YOUR type!"

The bovine suddenly perked up - "Wow, I never even thought of it that way, but if I remove four letters from my type, I'm left with MY name!"

"And we never even had to rearrange the letters for any of them," the cat said.

> What three elemental animals were chatting here?

Comment: Perhaps as an extension to this puzzle, challenge users to come up with as many of these as possible (animal-element correspondence)?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, and great first puzzle! :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The three animals are...

> **Cobalt Colt** (-BA)
>   **Lead Leopard** (+OPR)
>  **Oxygen Ox** (-YGEN)

(Credit to Deusovi for nailing the format right away and for the bovine answer.  Thanks to KeyboardWielder for the hint on #2.)

Alternate answer for #2:

> **Silicon Lion** (-SIC)
> [if 'type' can refer to animal type, rather than element]

Comment: Ah you got there just before me..

Comment: SO CLOSE but the second one is wrong. Read that clue again...

Comment: That said, I actually like your second answer better, because it would make the three clues consistent. I'm considering changing the puzzle to use your solution!

Comment: Your alternate doesn't work for the same reason your initial second answer doesn't...

Comment: @ColdFrog: Why not? Nothing's reordered.

Comment: I think he has a distinction between "type" and "name" in mind that I'm not getting.

Comment: Yeah - That's the only real clumsy bit I couldn't come up with a good way to remove. I hoped the differentiation might be evident after reading it and thinking of the kind of things that could be the solution but, *shrug*

Comment: I think the type is the element/adjective and the name is the animal/noun.  With that, the second answer should be easily... spotted.

Comment: I see it now.  Thanks KeyboardWielder.

Comment: Ok, fixed it so the OP's desired answer is primary.

Answer (score 3):

Two of the three animals are...

> a COBALT COB, and an OXYGEN OX.

Comment: Good start, but the horse loses 2 letters, not 3.